# Greek and English Language in bibliography using utf8 encoding and LaTeX

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, input-encodings, greek

I am creating a document;it's main language beeing greek. What I am trying to do, unsuccessfully is to have bibliography entries in two languages, Greek and English that is.

My code is

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{testbib.bib}
@comment Datei testbib.bib

@article{Mayer,
title = "The 11B(p,a)8Be nuclear reaction and 11B(p,p)11B backscattering cross sections for analytical purposes ",
journal = "Nuclear Instruments and Methods in Physics Research Section B: Beam Interactions with Materials and Atoms ",
volume = "143",
number = "3",
pages = "244 - 252",
year = "1998",
note = "",
issn = "0168-583X",
doi = "http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0168-583X(98)00383-8",
url = "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168583X98003838",
author = "M. Mayer and A. Annen and W. Jacob and S. Grigull",
language  ="English",
hyphenation="english"
}

@Mastersthesis{Vpaneta,
    author = "Συγγραφέας",
    title  = "Τίτλος",
    year   = "2012",
    month  = "μήνας",
    school = "Κατι",
    language  ="Greek",
    hyphenation="greek"
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
% \usepackage[bibencoding=auto,backend=biber,babel=other]{biblatex}
% \addbibresource{testbib.bib}

\newcommand{\sw}{\selectlanguage{english}}
\newcommand{\sq}{\selectlanguage{greek}}
\newcommand{\eng}[1]{\latintext#1\greektext}
\newcommand{\gre}[1]{\greektext#1\latintext}

\begin{document}
 \tableofcontents
 \chapter{Κεφάλαιο}
  \section{Ενότητα}
  σδφγηξκλ\cite{Mayer}hgfkhgjfkhgfkhg\cite{Vpaneta}
  \section{Ενότητα}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Βιβλιογραφία}
  \bibliographystyle{plain}
  %\selectlanguage{english}
  \bibliography{testbib}
  %\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Preferably I would like to use `utf8` encoding in order to have greek contents in the pdf viewer. However when using `utf8` encoding there's no way to produce the `.pdf` file. There are errors stating that

> Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:��2 not set up for use with LaTeX

therefore I have to use `iso-8859-7` encoding. Note that I change my editor's encoding accordingly.

What can I do to prefferably use a `utf8` encoding to create the bibliography and use 2 different languages or as a last solution to use `iso-8859-7` encoding to create in the same way(i.e. using 2 languages) the bibliography?

My output using `iso-8859-7` encoding is

[image]

When changing the language to English the output is

[image]

Comment: For multilingual bibliographies, `biblatex` is the only way to go (I don't think `babelbib` supports Greek).

Comment: @egreg : I am not sure if I am using `babelbib`... I think I am using `bibtex` or what is default when running quick build from `Kile`.

Comment: No, you're not using `babelbib`. Note that `@comment Datei testbib.bib` is syntactically incorrect and will produce errors.

Comment: I will erase it! Any idea how to produce the bibliography using `utf8`?

Comment: See section 3.10.3 in the documentation of biblatex

Comment: If I understand correctly I have to use `XeLaTeX`... I want to avoid this...A document that works with `LaTeX`, will produce errors when compiled with `XeLaTeX`...Isn't there another way without using package `biblatex`?

Comment: And you should compile your bibliography with `biber` (+biblatex). Biber understands utf8.

Comment: @Bernard : Thank you very much for your comment! How to compile with `biber` and `biblatex` in `kile`? I don't have a clue! Until now I am using `pdfLaTeX`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you don't need to use `XeLaTeX` with `biblatex`, it works with `pdflatex` too. You sample compiles fine for me with `pdflatex`, `utf8` option of `fontenc`, `biblatex` and `biber` for unicode bibliography support, and `fontenc` package with `T1` and `LGR` options for font support (although it seems it works even without `fontenc`):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{testbib.bib}

@article{Mayer,
title = "The 11B(p,a)8Be nuclear reaction and 11B(p,p)11B backscattering cross sections for analytical purposes ",
journal = "Nuclear Instruments and Methods in Physics Research Section B: Beam Interactions with Materials and Atoms ",
volume = "143",
number = "3",
pages = "244 - 252",
year = "1998",
note = "",
issn = "0168-583X",
doi = "http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0168-583X(98)00383-8",
url = "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168583X98003838",
author = "M. Mayer and A. Annen and W. Jacob and S. Grigull",
language  ="English",
hyphenation="english"
}

@Mastersthesis{Vpaneta,
    author = "Συγγραφέας",
    title  = "Τίτλος",
    year   = "2012",
    month  = "μήνας",
    school = "Κατι",
    language  ="Greek",
    hyphenation="greek"
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[T1,LGR]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
 \usepackage[bibencoding=auto,backend=biber,babel=other]{biblatex}
 \addbibresource{testbib.bib}

\newcommand{\sw}{\selectlanguage{english}}
\newcommand{\sq}{\selectlanguage{greek}}
\newcommand{\eng}[1]{\latintext#1\greektext}
\newcommand{\gre}[1]{\greektext#1\latintext}

\begin{document}
 \tableofcontents
 \chapter{Κεφάλαιο}
  \section{Ενότητα}
  σδφγηξκλ\cite{Mayer}hgfkhgjfkhgfkhg\cite{Vpaneta}
  \section{Ενότητα}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Βιβλιογραφία}
 % \bibliographystyle{plain}
  \selectlanguage{english}
  %\bibliography{testbib}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

compile it with

```
 pdflatex filename.tex
 biber filename
 pdflatex filename.tex
```

and of course, file `filename.tex` must be in `utf8` encoding
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I run `pdflatex file.tex`, then `biber file.tex` but I got errors `INFO - This is Biber 1.9
INFO - Logfile is 'testBibliography.tex.blg'
ERROR - Cannot find control file 'testBibliography.tex.bcf'! - did you pass the "backend=biber" option to BibLaTeX?
INFO - ERRORS: 1`...

Comment: @Thanos just run `biber filename`, without `.tex` extension. I will modify my answer.

Comment: Now it's working!!! Thank you very much for your help and time!!!

Comment: I've noticed sth weird. The entries `language="English"` appear on the text and I cannot change the style using `\bibliographystyle{plain}`. Is there a way around this?

Comment: @Thanos the `\bibliographystyle` command doesn't work with `biblatex`, you may use `style` package option. see the documentation, chapter `User guide`

Comment: @Thanos Just remove the `language` field from each bibliography entry if you don't want its contents printed. It is the `hyphenation` (preferred name `langid`) field that actually switches the language.

Comment: Hello. I've just tried to compile the code above and it didn't give me the result needed. Actually in the text it had the references in Greek, i.e. English words with greek letters. What I'm not doing right?

Comment: @giannis references are numerical, but normal English text is printed with Greek letters because Greek is selected as the document language